# ADFS 3.0 HRDCookieEnabled Not Working

Tags: authentication, active-directory, adfs, adfs3.0

I'm running ADFS 3.0, and have both ContextCookieEnabled and HRDCookieEnabled enabled. I also have a 30 day lifetime on my cookies.

The problem is that whenever a user selects and identity provider in the HRD screen, his choice is not remembered, which is to say, he is still presented with the HRD screen on subsequent visits. Any ideas what might be going on? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in the Sign In URL... this should be set to:

*https://adfstest.xxxxx.xxxxx/adfs/ls/*

Mine was erroneously set to:

*https://adfstest.xxxxx.xxxxx//adfs/ls/*

(Notice the extra slash before adfs)

I was using sharepoint, and to fix this, I did the following:

```
Set-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "ADFS" -SignInUrl https://adfstest.xxxxx.xxxxxx/adfs/ls/
```